# Node.js bitwise OR stops working for high numbers

Tags: node.js, integer, compression, logical-operators

I'm trying to "compress" an array of 16 `number`s ranging from 0 to 15 into a single `number`.

Since each element of the array is at most 15, I can represent it with just 4 bits, so I expect to have 4 bits * 16 = 64 bits which fits a `number`.

To do this "compression" I use the fallowing function:

```
function compressArray(array) {
  return array.reduce(
    (pre, curr, index) => {
      return (pre | (curr * Math.pow(2, index * 4)));
    },
    0
  );
}
```

But after index 8 it will keep giving me the same output without computing the correct `|`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Bitwise arithmetic in JavaScript is done on 32-bit numbers. Any number higher than this is forefully truncated to 32-bits. `2 ** 31 - 1 |  0 // 2147483647` while `2 ** 31 | 0 // -2147483648`

Comment: @VLAZ ahw thanks man, how can I fix this?

Comment: Not sure what the best way is. There is no native way to convert two 32-bit numbers into one 64 bit one and then back as bitwise operations are inherently unsafe there. I guess you could this by passing the conversion through a string `num.toString(2)` produces a binary number from any number, so you can chain string operations onto that to chop it up into small enough chunks and operate on this. Or there are [special collections](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects#Indexed_collections) that can help. Depends on what your goal is.

Comment: Hey thanks, can you make an answer so I can upvote (end eventually approve) it? :)

Comment: I don't think it's much of an answer. It's few suggestions that could be used as the basis of a solution but aren't solution of themselves. Without a clear goal, all I can provide is different options to pursue.